# Multiple log in as per role in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP. I am trying to create multiple log in for different role like: student,staff & admin

I have followed these tutorial: [Simple Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

admin log in is working currently.

now i want to create student log in using student controller & view.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'classes', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);

  function beforeFilter(){
    if (isset($this->params['admin'])) { 
        $this->layout = 'admin_default';
    }
    elseif (isset($this->params['student'])){
        $this->layout = 'student_default';
    }

    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
   }
 }
```

what should i do please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should not create a Students Controller if it have not a corresponding Student Model. Considering your request, you could implement something like this urls:

```
/admin/users/login
/student/users/login
/otherrole/users/login
```

just adding this to your config/core.php file:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

and creating your custom actions... for example admin_login, student_login and so on...

Check this out => http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing <= and (always) Happy Coding ;)

Comment: thank you for reply. yes i m trying to implement /student/users/login but it isn't working. i have created student_login() under UsersController & student_login.ctp under view/Users. m i doing something wrong so please guide me.

Comment: @chirag Did you add the 'student' string in the routing prefixes array? You should declare it as follow: Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'student'));

Comment: yes i have added it. public function student_login() {if ($this->request->is('post')) { if ($this->Auth->login()) { return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); } $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));}} is unable to authenticate any user.

Comment: You should first pass your conditions to the login() function: in the student_login() action you have to search only for users that belongs to the user group. For your login/auth issue, you should follow the CookBook guide that explains everything you need. In case of any problems maybe you will find this helpful => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816111/cakephp-email-login-auth/18848586#18848586

Comment: @chirag Hi, I have a similar scenario.. Did you manage to accomplish this? How exactly did you set it up, please. I am also very new to cakePHP and this confused me! Do you need to add all roles inside the array for the prefixes ? ie. array('admin', 'staff', 'other_role') ? Thanks

Comment: @user2678538, i have managed it manually, i have created on field named user_type in my users table & here the code for my AppController

Comment: if (isset($this->params['admin'])) { $this->layout = 'admin_default'; if($this->Auth->loggedIn()) { if($this->Auth->user('user_type') != 'admin') {return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/'.$this->Auth->user('user_type')));}}}elseif (isset($this->params['student'])){$this->layout = 'student_default';if($this->Auth->user('user_type') != 'student') {return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/'.$this->Auth->user('user_type')));}}